# How to make some part of WPF design common to multiple windows

Tags: wpf, vb.net

so I'm making this Visual Basic WPF and I have a navigation bar that will be common between multiple windows and I was wondering if there is a way to make a XAML and class only for this navigation bar and then import it to other windows so I don't have to copy and paste the same code every time I create a new window.

The current code:

MainWindow.vb

```
Class FloorWindow
    Private Sub SetAllInactive()
        ' This function will change all StackPanel objects
        ' of the navGrid to its inactive style which consists
        ' of opacity .1

        Dim childType As String

        For Each child In navGrid.Children
            childType = child.GetType().ToString()
            ' Check if child object of navGrid is a StackPanel
            If childType = "System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel" Then
                child.Opacity = 0.1
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub LogoBtnClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles logoBtn.Click
        Trace.WriteLine("Logo Clicked")
        ' Go to default page
        SetAllInactive()
        floorStack.Opacity = 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub FloorBtnClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles floorBtn.Click
        Trace.WriteLine("Floor Clicked")
        ' Go to floor page and change its stack to active attributes
        SetAllInactive()
        floorStack.Opacity = 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClientsBtnClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles clientsBtn.Click
        Trace.WriteLine("Clients Clicked")
        ' Go to floor page and change its stack to active attributes
        SetAllInactive()
        clientsStack.Opacity = 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub SettingsBtnClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles settingsBtn.Click
        Trace.WriteLine("Settings Clicked")
        ' Go to floor page and change its stack to active attributes
        SetAllInactive()
        settingsStack.Opacity = 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="FloorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RestaurantManager"
        xmlns:fa5="http://schemas.fontawesome.com/icons/"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Restaurant Floor" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="navGrid" Background=" #212121">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!-- Height of item menu should be same as width of the outter column -->
                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Menu Item Defenition Start -->
            <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0 0 0 .1"/>
            <Button x:Name="logoBtn" Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="10" TabIndex="10" Opacity="0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" Foreground="#03DAC5">
                E
            </TextBlock>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0 0 0 .1"/>
            <Button x:Name="floorBtn" Grid.Row="1" Panel.ZIndex="10" TabIndex="10" Opacity="0"/>
            <StackPanel x:Name="floorStack" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <fa5:SvgAwesome Icon="Solid_BorderAll" Width="20" Foreground="White"/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0">Floor</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <Border Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0 0 0 .1"/>
            <Button x:Name="clientsBtn" Grid.Row="2" Panel.ZIndex="10" TabIndex="10" Opacity="0"/>
            <StackPanel x:Name="clientsStack" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Opacity=".1">
                <fa5:SvgAwesome Icon="Solid_UserFriends" Width="20" Foreground="White"/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0">Clients</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <Border Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0 0 0 .1"/>
            <Button x:Name="settingsBtn" Grid.Row="3" Panel.ZIndex="10" TabIndex="10" Opacity="0"/>
            <StackPanel x:Name="settingsStack" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Opacity=".1">
                <fa5:SvgAwesome Icon="Solid_Cogs" Width="20" Foreground="White"/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0">Settings</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <!-- Menu Item Defenition End -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Easiest would be to make it it's own UserControl and then you can put it in the header of whichever window needs it.

Comment: @Kevin Cook, could you elaborate. Do you havê any documentários i could follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new `UserControl` (Project->Add User Control (WPF) in Visual Studio)
2. Move the "navGrid" element to be reused (cut and paste) from the `MainWindow` to the XAML markup of the newly created `UserControl`.

   The XAML markup of the `UserControl` should the look something like this:

   ```
    <UserControl ...
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RestaurantManager"
            xmlns:fa5="http://schemas.fontawesome.com/icons/">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="navGrid" Background=" #212121">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- Height of item menu should be same as width of the outter column -->
                    <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!-- Menu Item Defenition Start -->
                <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0 0 0 .1"/>
                <Button x:Name="logoBtn" Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="10" TabIndex="10" Opacity="0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" Foreground="#03DAC5">
                    E
                </TextBlock>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0 0 0 .1"/>
                <Button x:Name="floorBtn" Grid.Row="1" Panel.ZIndex="10" TabIndex="10" Opacity="0"/>
                <StackPanel x:Name="floorStack" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <fa5:SvgAwesome Icon="Solid_BorderAll" Width="20" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0">Floor</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <Border Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0 0 0 .1"/>
                <Button x:Name="clientsBtn" Grid.Row="2" Panel.ZIndex="10" TabIndex="10" Opacity="0"/>
                <StackPanel x:Name="clientsStack" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Opacity=".1">
                    <fa5:SvgAwesome Icon="Solid_UserFriends" Width="20" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0">Clients</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <Border Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0 0 0 .1"/>
                <Button x:Name="settingsBtn" Grid.Row="3" Panel.ZIndex="10" TabIndex="10" Opacity="0"/>
                <StackPanel x:Name="settingsStack" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Opacity=".1">
                    <fa5:SvgAwesome Icon="Solid_Cogs" Width="20" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0">Settings</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <!-- Menu Item Defenition End -->
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
   ```
3. Move any code (cut and paste) that is related to the navigation elements from the code-behind of the window to the code-behind of the `UserControl`
4. Add the `UserControl` to any window where you want to your common navigation bar:

   ```
    <Window x:Class="FloorWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RestaurantManager"
            xmlns:fa5="http://schemas.fontawesome.com/icons/"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="Restaurant Floor" Height="450" Width="800">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <local:UserControl1 />
            ...
        </Grid>
    </Window>
   ```

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help. +1 :)